# Unable to change data- value with data();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple html markup

```
<div class="this" data-info="false"></div>

$('.this').data('info');
```

returns correctly:  `false`

```
$('.this').data('info', 'true');
```

​​
`data-info` not changed!

[image]

Is there somthing I did it wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a value using `.data()`, jQuery uses it's own internal storage to keep track of the value, it doesn't update the attribute. If you want to do that, you'll need to use `.attr()`:

```
$('.this').attr('data-info', 'true');
```

You can see that the value is read correctly after setting it here: http://jsfiddle.net/6MN4G/

Answer (score 1):

I would use `jQuery('.this').attr('data-info','true');`

check it out here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/